Is the equality $E[\widehat{\epsilon}^\mathrm{T} \widehat{\epsilon}] = E[\widehat{\epsilon}^\mathrm{T}] E[\widehat{\epsilon}]$ valid in a Reg.Model?
In the context of a linear regression model, let $\epsilon$ denote the random vector of disturbances (errors) with $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$. The vector of residuals $\widehat{\epsilon}$ is defined as $\widehat{\epsilon} = M \epsilon$, where $M = I - H$ is idempotent and symmetric matrix and $H$ is a projection matrix.
I am trying to verify whether the following equality is valid:
$$
E[\widehat{\epsilon}^\mathrm{T} \widehat{\epsilon}] = E[\widehat{\epsilon}^\mathrm{T}] E[\widehat{\epsilon}].
$$
The dimension of  $\widehat{\epsilon}^\mathrm{T}$ is $n\times 1$ and $\widehat{\epsilon}$ is $1\times n$. Given that $E[\widehat{\epsilon}] = 0$ in ordinary least squares (OLS) regression, my intuition suggests that this equality might not hold, as the residual sum of squares involves a quadratic function of the residuals.
Could someone clarify whether this equality is valid or provide an explanation (e.g., using properties of the projection matrix $M$, the linearity of expectation, or independence)?


In general, $\mathbb E(XY)\ne \mathbb E X \mathbb E Y$, and especally in your case, as there's an obvious dependence.

Unless $\hat\epsilon$ is the zero vector, this equality is false. It stems from the fact that $\hat\epsilon ^T \hat\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^n \hat\epsilon ^2 _i $, where
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n \hat\epsilon ^2 _i] \ge 0,
$$
whereas, $\mathbb{E}[\hat \epsilon ] = \mathbb{E}[\hat y - y] = 0$ by definition, since this is (up to the sign value) the derivative w.r.t intercept term, i.e., we equate it to zero to find the minimum of the LS (the OLS estimators).

First, note that $\widehat{\epsilon} = (I - H)Y$, not $(I - H)\epsilon$, in the linear regression context. Also, as one commenter pointed out, it's very much not true $\mathbb{E}X^\top X = \mathbb{E}X^\top\mathbb{E}X$. But simplifying your expression anyway,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\widehat{\epsilon}^\top \widehat{\epsilon} = \mathbb{E}Y^\top(I-H)^\top(I-H)Y = \mathbb{E}Y^\top(I-H)Y = \dim(I - H) \sigma^2 = (n-p) \sigma^2
\end{align*}
where we normally say $\dim(H) = p$.
